# cannot resolve method 'addToRequestQueque(com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest,java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, android

Im going to make a database in php my sql using android studio

but this error is in the way

```
//Adding request to request queue
            AndroidLoginController.getInstance();

            addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
        }
```

I receive the error cannot resolve method 'addToRequestQueque(com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest,java.lang.String)'

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.example.pjsr.brnp.MainActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import prefs.UserInfo;
import prefs.UserSession;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = Login.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText email, password;
    private Button login;
    private TextView signup;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private UserSession session;
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.open_signup);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


        session = new UserSession(this);
        userInfo = new UserInfo(this);

        if (session.isUserLoggedin()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();

        }

        login.setOnClickListener(this);
        signup.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void login(final String email, final String password) {
        //Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in....");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Utils.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    //check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        //now store the user in SQLite
                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String uName = user.getString("username");
                        String email = user.getString("email");

                        //Inserting row in users table
                        userInfo.setEmail(email);
                        userInfo.setUsername(uName);
                        session.setLoggedin(true);

                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        //error in login, get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        toast(errorMsg);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    //json error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    toast("Json error: " + e.getMessage());

                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                toast("Unknown Error occured");
                progressDialog.hide();
            }

        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                //Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;

            }
        };


//Adding request to request queue
        AndroidLoginController.getInstance();

        addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void toast(String x) {
        Toast.makeText(this, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                String uName = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();

                login(uName, pass);
                break;
            case R.id.open_signup:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SignUp.class));
                break;

        }
    }


    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Login Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`addToRequestQueue` is a method defined for the volley application controller which seems to be `AndroidLoginController` in your case. Change the line to

`AndroidLoginController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strRe‌​q,tag_string_req)`

This is assuming you have created the singleton using standard volley tutorials or android developer documentation